# "zsh: command not found: ssh -Y" on mac terminal

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

I am trying to connect to a remote server using ssh, it used to work with no problem when I started the terminal and did

```
ssh -Y <user@address>
```

However, now I keep getting the following error:

> zsh: command not found: ssh -Y ...

I was trying to look for an answer to solve this but couldn't, I guess it is something with the PATH? I also tried to add `sudo` in front of the command but still get the same error.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you paste the command? or did you type it? What changed in (or to) your shell between "it used to work" and "however, now … error"?

Comment: If your error message is accurate, your command is not `ssh -Y user@address` but something like `"ssh -Y" user@address`.